# Liter as a lower case letter in siunitx

Tags: siunitx

In german the unit "liter" is usually abbreviated with the lower case "l".
But no matter whether I use `\qty{}{\liter}` or `\qty{}{\litre}`, the unit is always abbreviated with the capital letter "L".
Any suggestions how to fix this?

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\qty{2}{\liter} oder \qty{2}{\litre}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should declare `\litre` with the symbol you want

```latex
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\litre}{l}
\begin{document}

\qty{2}{\liter} oder \qty{2}{\litre}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could it be that in earlier versions of siunitx `\litre` was abbreviated with the lower case letter "l" and not "L"?

Comment: Perhaps there should be a package option for this: the symbol for the liter is either l or L: both are accepted and `siunitx` should not force either (maybe with l as default, because it's listed first in the brochure).

Comment: @egreg The documentation of `siunitx` actually clarifies that: "In  contrast  to  metres,  however,  there  is  more  likelihood  of  users  wishing  to adjust the appearance of litres:  both 'l' and 'L' are commonly used.  The recommended approach to adjustment is to re-declare the `\litre` macro, as `\liter` will follow automatically. `\DeclareSIUnit\litre{l}`" (p. 52).

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf I find it really awkward, because I spell “liter”. Also the symbol “L” is almost never used in Italy, for instance and it's almost always ”l”.

Comment: @egreg Yeah well, I also prefer "l" instead of "L", but some journals insist in it, and it is a valid abbreviation. Personally, I appreciate that `\litre` is the default macro (in contrast to `liter`), but that is just my preference for British English. At least it is declared in the manual, but having it as an option for `sisetup` may be the preferable option for some future update... I think this is (at least nearly) the only SI-abbreviation where two options are equally correct.

Comment: When I used `siunitx` about a month ago, I seem to remember that either `\liter` or `\litre` was abbreviated with the lowercase "l". It is a pity that I have to enter an extra command to correctly display the unit in german now.

Comment: If you are disappointed with the recent non-backwards-compatible changes to the package (as I was) you can use `\usepackage{siunitx}[=v2]`

Comment: @egreg The one piece of customisation that is _not_ keyval based is the symbols for units: that's what `\DeclareSIUnit` is for, and is why I've deprecated `\SIUnitSymbol...`. So I feel an option here is 'the wrong message'.

Comment: @Schubladenzieher You are correct: when I reflected on it, I felt relying on a spelling variant for `l` vs `L` was not the best interface decision.

Comment: @RobinGeorg I stepped the major version as there were breaking changes - the biggest one is the font selection system (which was really an issue), but ironically it's the one change no-one seems to mind. I have tried as far as possible to avoid breaking changes, but at the same time there are places I can see I got things not just a bit awkward but out-and-out wrong.